# PHP Script on <h1> on Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using "Revusion - Flat Corporate Wordpress Theme", there is a default setting that when you add a page title it is assigned a H1 status and assigned CSS like so in the media.css file of the theme.

```
#pagetitle-container h1, #pagetitle-container h3 {
font-size:30px;
font-family:'Raleway', Helvetica, Arial;
font-weight:300;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#fff;
position:relative;
margin:0px 0px -30px 0px;
bottom:2px;
}
```

The problem is as you may know for google SEO and Analytics I have been ordered to only have one H1 tag per page. I would like that this page title header would not be a H1 as I have my own H1 I would like to use on the page, in the body for example.

So the PHP, that I believe is doing it is below. How could I change it that the pageheader is a H6 for example. It can't be as simple as changing the h1 -> h6? 
Its just in short I want only the one h1 on the page, the one for example you can set with the 'visual editor' in wordpress.

```
<!-- pagetitle start here -->
<section id="pagetitle-container" <?php if($bg) echo'style="background:'.$bg.'"'; ?>>
    <div class="row"> 
        <?php if($page_breadcrumb_onoff==1){?>          
        <div class="five column breadcrumb">
            <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display')){?>

            <?php 
            echo '<ul>';
            bcn_display_list();
            echo '</ul>';
            ?>

            <?php }else{ ?>

            <ul><?php if (function_exists('indonez_breadcrumbs')) indonez_breadcrumbs(); ?></ul>

            <?php }?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="<?php if($page_breadcrumb_onoff==1){echo 'seven';}else{echo 'twelve';} ?> column pagetitle">
        <?php 

        if(is_singular('portfolio') || is_singular('team') || is_singular('client')) :

            echo '<h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1>';    

        elseif(is_attachment()):

            echo '<h1>'.get_the_title().'</h1>';

        elseif(is_single() || is_home()) :

            echo '<h1>'.$blog_title.'</h1>';    

        elseif(is_archive()):

            echo '<h3>';
            if ( is_day() ) :
            printf( __( '<span>%s</span>', 'indonez' ), get_the_date() );
            elseif ( is_month() ) :
            printf( __( '<span>%s</span>', 'indonez' ), get_the_date('F Y') );
            elseif ( is_year() ) :
            printf( __( '<span>%s</span>', 'indonez' ), get_the_date('Y') );
            elseif ( is_author()) :
            printf( __( 'Archives %s', 'indonez' ), "<a class='url fn n' href='" . get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) . "' title='" . esc_attr( get_the_author() ) . "' rel='me'>" . get_the_author() . "</a>" );

            elseif ( is_search()) :
            printf( __( 'Search Results', 'indonez' ), '<span></span>' );

            else :
            printf( __( '%s', 'indonez' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
            endif;
            echo '</h3>';

        elseif(is_search()):

            echo ' <h1>';
            printf( __( 'Search Result', 'indonez' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' );
            echo '</h1>';

        elseif(is_404()):

            echo ' <h1>'.__( 'ERROR 404', 'indonez' ).'</h1>';

        endif;
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>        
</section>
<!-- pagetitle end here -->
```

Ok so I found this code also in a 'theme-functions.php' file.
I am really sorry if it is of no use, as I have not got a strong
knowledge of PHP as of yet, it may or may not help

```
$custom_css .= '#mainmenu ul, #menu li ul a,#menu li ul a:visited, #pagetitle-container h1, #pagetitle-container h3, .pageof, .wp-pagenavi .pages, .wp-pagenavi .extend, .pages a, .pages .current, .wp-pagenavi a, .wp-pagenavi .current, a.comment-reply-link, a.comment-reply-link:visited, #cancel-comment-reply-link, .tag-cloud, .grey-column.custom_bg h1, .grey-column.custom_bg h2, .grey-column.custom_bg h3, .grey-column.custom_bg h4, .grey-column.custom_bg h5, .grey-column.custom_bg h6
    {font-family:'.$font1.', Helvetica, Arial}'."\n";

    $custom_css .= 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6, .circle-border p, table th, .testi-name{font-family:'.$font2.', Helvetica, Arial}'."\n";

    $custom_css .= 'a:link,a:visited,a:active, ul.tabs li.active a, ul.tabs-left li.active a, ul.tabs-right li.active a, ul.tabs-bottom li.active a, .breadcrumb ul li.current-page, #pf-filter ul li a:hover, #pf-filter ul li a:active, #pf-filter ul li a.selected, .post-info ul li a:hover, ul.popular-list li p.comment-count a, ul.popular-list li p.comment-count a:visited, .text-info{color:'.$generalcolor.'}'."\n";

    $custom_css .= '.post-type, aside .widget-title, .sitemap-heading h4, .rdm, .widget_search button, #searchform button, .widget_search button:hover, #searchform button:hover, .highlight, .circle-border:hover, .pages a, .wp-pagenavi a, .wp-pagenavi .pages, .teaser:hover .teaser-preview-box, .teaser:hover .teaser-gallery-box, button[type="submit"], input[type="submit"], input[type="button"]{background:'.$generalcolor.'}'."\n";

    if($generalcolor!=""){
    $custom_css .='.rdm:hover, button[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="submit"]:hover, input[type="button"]:hover{background:'.$buttonhover.'}'."\n";
    }

    if($generalcolor!=""){
    $custom_css .= '.teaser-preview-box, #map, .google_map{border-color:'.$generalcolor.'}'."\n";
    }

    $custom_css .= 'ul.tabs-right li.active a{border-right:solid 1px '.$generalcolor.'}'."\n";
    $custom_css .= 'ul.tabs-left li.active a{border-left:solid 1px '.$generalcolor.'}'."\n";
    $custom_css .= 'ul.tabs-top li.active a, ul.tabs li.active a{border-top:solid 1px '.$generalcolor.'}'."\n";
    $custom_css .= 'ul.tabs-bottom li.active a{border-bottom:solid 1px '.$generalcolor.'}'."\n";

    $custom_css .= 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{color:'.$headingcolor.'}'."\n";

    $custom_css .= '#top-info{background:'.$topareabg.'}'."\n";
    $custom_css .= '#top-info, #top-info span, #top-info a, #top-info a:visited{color:'.$topareatext.'}'."\n";

    $custom_css .= '#mainmenu-wrapper{background:'.$menuareabg.'}'."\n";

    if($menuareabg!=""){
    $custom_css .= '#mainmenu-wrapper{border-color:'.$bordermenuarea.'}'."\n";
    }

    $custom_css .= '#mainmenu-wrapper, #mainmenu-wrapper .socials-list li a, #mainmenu-wrapper .socials-list li a:visited, #mainmenu-wrapper #top-socials  a, #mainmenu-wrapper #top-socials  a:visited{color:'.$socialiconcolor.'}'."\n";

    $custom_css .= '#mainmenu ul li a, #mainmenu ul li li a:hover, #mainmenu ul li li:hover > a
                    #mainmenu ul li li.current_page_item > a, #mainmenu ul li li.current_page_item:hover > a,
                    #mainmenu ul li li.current_page_parent > a, #mainmenu ul li li.current_page_parent:hover > a,
                    #mainmenu ul li li.current-menu-parent > a, #mainmenu ul li li.current-menu-parent:hover > a,
                    #mainmenu ul li li.current-menu-item > a, #mainmenu ul li li.current-menu-ancestor > a{color:'.$menucolor.'}'."\n";

    $custom_css .= '#mainmenu ul li:hover,
                    #mainmenu li.current_page_item,
                    #mainmenu li.current_page_parent,
                    #mainmenu li.current-menu-parent,
                    #mainmenu li.current-menu-item{background:'.$bgmenucolor.'}'."\n";

    if($bgmenucolor!=""){
    $custom_css .= '#mainmenu ul li:hover,
                    #mainmenu li.current_page_item,
                    #mainmenu li.current_page_parent,
                    #mainmenu li.current-menu-parent,
                    #mainmenu li.current-menu-item{border-color:'.$bordermenuactive.'}'."\n";
    }

    $custom_css .= '#menu li ul a,#menu li ul a:visited{color:#828282;}';

    $custom_css .= '#slideshow-container{background:'.$slideshowbg.'}'."\n";

    $custom_css .= 'footer{background:'.$footerbg.'}'."\n";
    $custom_css .= 'footer ul li a, footer ul li a:visited, footer p{color:'.$footertextcolor.' !important}'."\n";
    if($footertextcolor!=""){
    $custom_css .= 'footer ul li a:hover{color:'.$footermenuhover.' !important}'."\n";
    }
    $custom_css .= 'footer h1, footer h2, footer h3, footer h4, footer h5, footer h6{color:'.$footerheadingcolor.'}'."\n";
    $custom_css .= 'footer .circle-social li, footer .circle-icon, footer .square-social li, footer .square-icon {background:'.$footersocialcolor.'}'."\n";
    $custom_css .= 'footer .circle-social li:hover, footer .square-social li:hover, footer .circle-icon:hover, footer .square-icon:hover {background:'.$footersocialhover.'}'."\n";
```

Comment: yes, it is that simple. However, if you change every h1 tag in that template to an h2 tag, you haven't said how are you planning to add your unique h1. Are you planning on doing that manually in the header template?

Comment: no i was just thinking that I could change the css in the base.css file to suit me. Below is the script there  (can't format it here sorry)                                    /***** Typography *****/
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
font-family:'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial;
font-weight:300;
padding:0;
color:#71a0c0;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
margin-top: 0.2em;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
line-height: 1.2125em;
}

h1 a,h2 a,h3 a,h4 a,h5 a,h6 a {font-weight:inherit;}

h1 {font-size: 38px;}
h2 {font-size: 31px;}
h3 {font-size: 26px;}
h4 {font-size: 22px;}
h5 {font-size: 20px;}
h6 {font-size: 18px;}

Comment: Let's start over: if you change every occurence of h1 in the current template, your site won't have any h1. I believe you were told to have just one h1, not none.

Comment: ok well, i thought that the above php, was code to assign a h1 to the page title and the page title alone. I did not know it was controlling all instances of h1. You are right I do need h1.

Comment: the above template seems to be controlling the h1 for the site header section. You got that right. But you said that you wanted to avoid the default behavior of page titles being displayed in h1 tags. I believe you need to clarify what's the current behavior and what's the desired behavior. Also, it's not clear if now you're dealing with two h1 tags.

Comment: ok as it is, lets say i want to add a page. This page will contain a Title "Title Here" this will default to a H1 [i.e. css & PHP above]. I don't want that. Lets say in the main body, I want to have a column heading as my h1, so lets say in the box where you add content in wordpress CMS, I have a header like <h1> Why Cant I be the Only H1</h1>  So there lies the problem, on these pages I want others to use the CMS and decide on there H1, rather that the Page Title been a h1 as well, making two. I hope that is clear.

Comment: @amenadiel I added a wee bit of code, i say wee bit lightly. I added some code from another PHP file, if it will be of any help. [added to question above]

Comment: Its funny, even if I change the Page Title to a H4 by declaring it h4 in the G.U.I. that you can override it, it will throw in a blank H1. :-0